# What is DBML storage attribute in LINQ to SQL?

Tags: database, linq

I am currently working on a project that uses LINQ to SQL for database access.  It has become necessary for me to manually update the DBML file by right-clicking on it and opening it with an XML editor because I do not want to re-generate the file and lose all of the changes that have been made to association member names.

Can someone please explain to me what the storage attribute is used for in the Association element of the DBML file?  I have searched this forum and Google to no avail.  The storage attribute is not present in every Association element.  I have included XML in my DBML that both includes and excludes the storage attribute below:

```
  <Association Name="Customer_WorkOrder" Member="Customer" ThisKey="CustomerId" OtherKey="Id" Type="Customer" IsForeignKey="true" />

  <Association Name="Sycode_WorkOrder" Member="WorkOrderOrderStatus" Storage="_Sycode" ThisKey="OrderStatus" OtherKey="recno" Type="Sycode" IsForeignKey="true" />
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.dataattribute.storage.aspx

> Gets or sets a private storage field to hold the value from a column.

If there is no value set, it generates the private field like "_" + AssociationName, otherwise it uses the "storage" value. It is a bit confusing, since usually the "storage" term refers to the database and not to the generated code.